# Upload custom Bootstrap template in Liferay 6.2

Tags: jquery, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I followed this [tutorial](https://web.liferay.com/es/web/marcos.castro/blog/-/blogs/bootstrap-3-in-liferay-6-2-yes-that-s-possible) and I was able to work with Bootstrap 3.3.7 in Liferay 6.2.

But know I want to know if it's possible to upload a web template like the ones you can find [here](https://w3layouts.com/) into my liferay theme.

Should I put the template's source files into bs3 directory?

Am I going to have troubles with the jQuery files?

Thanks for answering I am a really newbie in all this Liferay stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have any problem if you put a template. I've done quite a few projects in Liferay 6.2 with Bootstrap 3 for 2-3 years now ... And I've never had any problems. My advice is that you use Gulp-theme to generate themes:

[Gulp Theme task](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-theme-tasks)

Greetings from Spain

Comment: Thanks. I've tried but the template seems like an image. I am unable to select something or to make it work, for now.

Comment: @LenaVonEngel These example: https://github.com/marcoscv-work/Liferay-6.2-with-Bootstrap-3.x-theme